# Karoubi envelope of a ring as a category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Given a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$. We can consider $R$ as an additive category $\mathcal R$ with one object $*$ and homomorphisms $\hom(*,*)=R$. One can form the idempotent completion of $\mathcal R$ (aka its Karoubi envelope), which is the universal category where every idempotent of $\mathcal R$ splits.

**Question:** What is the idempotent completion in this special case? Is there any ring-theoretic description of it? Is it, for instance, again a ring?

Comment: No, it won't be a ring, unless for the pathetic ring where $0=1$, we will have at least 2 different objects in the resulting category, one for $0$ and one for $1$ (and further objects for further idempotents).

Comment: You may find [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ab-enriched+category#as_a_generalisation_of_rings) interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a small category $C$, the idempotent completion can be identified with the full subcategory of presheaves on $C$ which are retracts of objects in $C$.

In your case, a functor $F:R\to Set$ is simply a set $S:=F(\ast)$ equipped with a left $R$-action. The yoneda embedding of the unique object $\ast\in R$ is simply $R$, viewed as a set equipped with the obvious $R$-action. If $S$ is a retract of $R$, then there are morphisms of lets $R$-sets $i:S\to R$ and $r:R\to S$ such that $ri={\rm id}:S\to S$.

Since $i$ and $r$ are in particular functions, $i$ must be injective. Since $i$ is a map of left $R$-sets, the image of $i$ must be closed under the $R$-action. Moreover, $i(S)$ must actually be a principal ideal in $R$, since $r:R\to S$ is surjective and therefore $i(r(1))\in i(S)$ must generate $\ i(S)$. Even more, $i(r(1))$ must be idempotent, since $rir=r$.

So the category you are looking for is the category of principal ideals, generated by idempotents in $R$, with morphisms given by $R$-module maps between them.

Notice that if you have an idempotent $e\in R$, then the corresponding map in the idempotent completion is multiplication on the left by $e$: 
$$e:R\to R$$
This idempotent is split since we can take $S=eR$ and then $e=i\circ e$ and ${\rm id}=e\circ i$.

Comment: Note that an idempotent in a ring corresponds to a projection out of a direct product decomposition, which gives a somewhat more concrete description of your category: it's the category of all direct factors of $R$.